# Remap key within remmina doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, x11, remote-desktop, remap

I am running x-window on my linux pc, with remmina to remote access windows xp PC
I've swapped capslock and left ctrl in my Xmodmap file, and load it in xsession file.

Here is my Xmodmap file, located at ~/.Xmodmap

```
#!/bin/bash
SYSMODMAP="/etc/X11/Xmodmap"
USRMODMAP="$HOME/.Xmodmap"

if [ -x /usr/bin/X11/xmodmap ]; then
     if [ -f "$SYSMODMAP" ]; then
       xmodmap "$SYSMODMAP"
     fi
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/X11/xmodmap ]; then
     if [ -f "$USRMODMAP" ]; then
      xmodmap "$USRMODMAP"
     fi
fi
```

This is my xsession file, located at ~/.xsession

```
! Swap Caps_Lock and Control_L
! 
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L  
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

It worked in my x-window environment, however, it doesn't work in my remote windows PC.

I have modified registry in windows to swap capslock and ctrl, and it worked if I use windows's physical keyboard.

I have searched a lot on web, someone seems having solving this problem by enable "using client key map" in remmina's configuration tab, however, it doesn't work for me.

I wander which keymap file does remmina load, so I can modify them to fit my need. Does any one has the same problem?

Comment: I can confirm that I have this problem on a Linux Mint system; if I swap the keys using /usr/bin/setxbmap, Remmina is the only program which _doesn't_ actually obey.

Comment: update: finally I gave up and using remote-desktop instead.

Comment: See also [Remmina RDP key remapping on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/797355).